# Bluetooth not working on Windows 8 on HP G6-2105TX laptop

Tags: windows-8, bluetooth

I have a HP G6-2105 TX laptop.  I upgraded it to windows 8.  All drivers worked fine except the Bluetooth driver.  I cannot detect any device through my laptop and no device sees my laptop.  I installed the Broadcom drivers from official HP site.  But that did not work either.  Why is Bluetooth not working?

Comment: what bluetooth chipset does the laptop have?

Comment: Its the broadcom one.If this is not the right thing you are asking for so kindly let me know for how shall i find the chipset for bluetooth then

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the right driver. Install it over, if needed.

Or maybe the website doesn't give Windows 8 compatible drivers, or the wrong one. Would be surprising and silly, but who knows. Try this, maybe: http://www.broadcom.com/

In last resort, you can try updating your drivers with software such as Driver Genius (which you can find here : http://www.driver-soft.com/ )

The most sad outcome would be if the device just isn't compatible with Windows 8 (yet?). I don't think it's the case, but again, who knows. You could email the manufacturer of your device to know.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But i tried installing via broadcom site.Which did not work too.So have you hear about Bluetooth Command line software.So suing that atleast i have made my device discoverable but still cannot pair it with my laptop

Comment: Sorry, I know no such thing. At this point, if I were you, I would either use a third-party software ( http://alternativeto.net/software/driver-genius/ ) or just write the manufacturer.

Comment: Tried with third party software i.e driver genius but no improvements still.The laptop manufacturer to whom i contacted tried all the things to improve but of no use.so they now say me to have a clean install of windows which i dont want to.

Comment: Ew. Then I'm sorry, but I think that's about how much I can help. Gotta hope someone else can.

Comment: Thank you.By the way i have posted the same question in microsoft forum.Got a suggestion.But that didnt work too.Hoping for a better reply which would help me soon

Comment: I can attach the error i get while connecting....Its this:
http://imgur.com/mtgxm

Comment: Yeah, no, sorry. I was acting sort of blindfolded from the start, with general advice for device/driver problems. I've never owned a single bluetooth device. Really, you need someone else. ._.